# Rails API Helpers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-api

I have Ruby version `2.3.0` and I am using rails version `5.0.0beta3`. I am making an api and I used the `rails new app --api` command to make my app.

In the early stages of development, I realized that the helper classes are not included in api applications.

For example, I would like to have a authenticate helper method for my session controller.

Is there any way to add back manually?

Comment: helper methods don't make sense in api applications, because they are meant to be used in views and api applications don't have any views.

Comment: API applications typically don't use sessions - for each request the caller would send some token for authentication and the API will verify this token. I don't know why you need a "session controller" in an API app.

Comment: Well, they would be useful to clean up some of my controller code as well, like a sign_in method that my controller could use.

Comment: And yes @Zabba, I know, I use token based authentication, the logged_in? method would see if the token is valid, etc.

Comment: "logged in" does not make sense in an api application because there is no session. If you had a method named "authenticate", that would be clearer that "authenticate" should be called before every action in your api.

Comment: Ok, I updated my question, @Zabba

Comment: A "helper" method is meant to be used in views, and is available only in views - helper methods are not available in a controller. (you can use a controller method as a help though, with helper_method :x). So if you are referring to "some method somewhere that is like a 'helper' but not a Rails 'helper'", then that makes sense. Is that what you want? If so, you can use a controller concern or write your own class for authentication and call that.